# Software for Scheduling Maintenance Windows for customer infrastructure

Tags: calendar, cloud, jira, sysadmin, azure

We produce a software for our customers.

Sometimes we need to schedule a maintenance window and we would like to take note of such window and expose this calendar to our affected customers.

Ideally the software should:

1. Expose a calendar to our customers, and customers should not know one each other
2. List all maintenance update for DevOps but such list shouldn't be exposed to the customers
3. List the resources that will be affected
4. List the number of minutes7hours of downtime expected
5. Integration with Jira or Zendesk or Google Calendar
6. Cloud native or compatible with Azure

Does a software like that exists?

Or something similar at least?